# Getting special charcter inside table after insert using PHP and Mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I have an issue while inserting data into database using PHP and MySQL. I am explaining my code below.

```
$description=mysqli_real_escape_string($connect,"Big Rock AGD 6 pk for $8.99 ​/ 15pk $18.49");
$userqry=mysqli_query($connect,'INSERT INTO db_gallery
(description) values ("'.$description.'")');
```

But after inserting the some special character are coming with description inside table which is given below.

```
id                            description

1                   Big Rock AGD 6 pk for $8.99 â€‹/ 15pk $18.49
```

Here my description column data type is `text` and I dont need to insert that `â€‹` special character with original description. Please help me.

Comment: I cannot reproduce your error. if you do var_dump with $description what is the output?

Comment: Likely a charset issue. Set the connection, PHP header and the database to UTF-8.

Comment: You may remove special character by preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z0-9\s]/", "", $string);

Comment: Maybe you can use `htmlspecialchars()` which would convert `&` into `&amp` and does this with more characters

Comment: @HaotianLiu : $description output is `Big Rock AGD 6 pk for $8.99 ​/ 15pk $18.49`.

Comment: @subhra loop through your all data store your description field into variable then change like: `$description = preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z0-9\s]/", "", $description);` And update this in your table

Answer (score 0):

Use [`htmlspecialchars()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php).

```
$description = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, htmlspecialchars("Big Rock AGD 6 pk for $8.99 ​/ 15pk $18.49"));
// Makes: Big Rock AGD 6 pk for &#36;8.99 ​/ 15pk &#36;18.49
$userqry = mysqli_query($connect,"INSERT INTO `db_gallery`
(`description`) values ('$description')");
```

When you get the description from the database `&#36;` is converted to: $ by HTML.

Switch double and single quotes in your query makes it al lot easier to read. It also doesn't require you to use `.` inside the query.

The backticks `` ` `` are used around table and column names to prefent mysql reserverd words error.

Comment: I used `htmlspecialchars` still issue is same.

Answer (score 0):

you need to change table format

**1)change database format**

```
ALTER DATABASE Database_Name CHARACTER SET utf8;
```

**2)change table format**

```
ALTER TABLE Your CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8;
```

after this your probelm will be solved